# JQuery UI dialog showing waiting message until ajax call is processed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, callback

I think that all is in the title. When I started this I thought it will be a 5 minutes codes or a quick result when googling... But It's now three hours I'm on this:

Just show a dialog, with a "Please Wait..." message, while I'm performing an ajax call to retrieve some json result, and then show a "Result complete".

```
$('#switchOff').live("click",function(){

   $('#dialog').dialog({
                modal:true,

               open: function(){
// I would like to call myAjax function
//From here ?
// While my dialog is showing the Wait message...
               },


                complete: function(){
//close the dialog when fished
                 $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                         },
   }); 



});

function ajaxCall() {
                //my ajax call
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? Why don't you show your JS code??!?

Comment: Excuse me..
Why you don't call Jquery's dialog after ajax call's processed??

Comment: As I described my problem, in fact I would like to first display the dialog: $("#myDialogBox").dialog(); And after call the ajax...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not use `live` anymore.  Use `.on` instead.  You are mixing up the dialog an ajax code. Here is an example of how I would do it.

[Here is link to fiddle for demonstation](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/EjpD3/)

```
$('#switchOff').on("click",  ajaxCall);

$("#loading").dialog({
    hide: 'slide',
    show: 'slide',
    autoOpen: false
});

function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: { html: '<p>JSON result</p>' , delay: 3},
        method: 'post',
        beforeSend: function(){
           $("#loading").dialog('open').html("<p>Please Wait...</p>");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loading').html("<p>Result Complete...</p>");
            $('#ajaxResult').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ".on" is apparently used with the recent version of JQuery. But I'm using JQuery 1.5... Because of some old function I have to migrate. But your solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok

With this comment

```
  `As I described my problem, in fact I would like to first display the dialog: $("#myDialogBox").dialog();` 

And after call the ajax..
```

The solution is:

From the click on the button `id="btn"`

```
$( "#btn_Deletepara" ).click(function() {
                $( "#JQUERY'sDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
//Now you Call the ajax
            });
```

Or

```
$( "#JQUERY'sDialog" ).dialog({

Add your script for call ajax
```

Comment: Thanks Mirko for the response, I added some code, but I tried so many times that I don't know which code to keep... Your code is very close to the one I added. but it seems that it's not working.... (For me !)